# Django ModuleNotFoundError: No module named while importing from a folder

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to run a command that is supposed to import the models from an upper folder
[image]

I'm trying to run crate_university.py which is on the assessments/university/commands directory
This should be importing from the models which is located at assessments/university/ folder

I have the following code:

```
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand

from university.models import University, TeacherDegree, Teacher
```

Buen when I try to run the command I get the following error:

[image]

Comment: have you included your app in the installed_apps in settings.py?

Comment: you probably need `from assessments.university.models import ...` or add assessments to your python path